# How to use wildcard attribute name and contains()?

Tags: xpath

In my problem I search for elements that have an example structure like:

```
<ngc-product-card ng-reflect-signup-type="comprehensive">
```

Since the elements may have the *comprehensive* value stored in another attribute, say:

```
<new-ngc-product-card data-label="comprehensive signup">
```

hence I would like to use a wildcard-attribute-name search and also apply the *contains()* function like:

```
//*[contains(@*,"comprehensive")]
```

which doesn't work
What does work is

```
//*[@*="comprehensive"]
```

Is there any way to use both '@*' and 'contains()' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do.

```
//*[@*[contains(., "comprehensive")]]
```